Soul does not allow acronyms to be expanded
I get a "Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed" message when using an acronym for the first time in the \hl environment, where it should appear in its extended form.
Instead of the acronym, a black box appears.

Here is an MWE:
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{AC}{acronym}
\end{acronym}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\hl{This is a text where the  \mbox{\ac{AC}} appears for the first time.}

\hl{This is a text where the \mbox{\ac{AC}} appears for the second time.}

\end{document}

P.S. the concept suggested here:
How to use soul with glossaries to space-out acronyms?
doesn't work for me.
Thanks!

Welcome to TeX.SE! We do not have your inputed file acronyms, so we can not run your code. Please make the code compilable!

@Mensch, I updated my question. Thanks.

If you can use LuaLaTeX, it's better to use the lua-ul package to highlight text. https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-ul

@User23456234, thanks, but I must use pdfLaTeX.

After delving into the implementation of soul/soul-ori it seems \soulregister\ac{7} might do the trick.
(The documentation says nothing about the possibility of registering with value 7, but...)
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{AC}{acronym}
\end{acronym}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\soulregister\ac{7}

\begin{document}

\hl{This is a text where the \ac{AC} appears for the first time.}

\hl{This is a text where the \ac{AC} appears for the second time.}

\end{document}


Thanks, but \mbox{\noexpand\noexpand\noexpand\ac{AC}} prevents the acronym from expanding, even if it is its first appearance. That’s not what I meant.

@Eyal Sorry for not realizing this. :-(  But it seems \soulregister\ac{7} might do the trick. I edited my answer accordingly.

It works. Thanks!
